# Query doesn't work on c# but work on powershell

Tags: c#, process, win32-process

Anyone know why my query `"select Name, ProcessID, Caption from Win32_Process where ProcessId='" + processIds[index] + "'"` return

```
 Column 'Name' does not belong to table Win32_Process
```

in my program C#.

In powershell when I execute

```
Get-WmiObject -query "select Name, ProcessID, Caption from win32_process"
```

It's works !

```
   String queryString = "select Name, ProcessID, Caption from Win32_Process where ProcessId='" + processIds[index] + "'";
                SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery(queryString);

                ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
                options.Authentication = System.Management.AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;


                ManagementScope scope = new System.Management.ManagementScope("\\root\\cimv2");
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
                try
                {
                    ManagementObjectCollection processes = searcher.Get();
                    DataTable result = new DataTable();
                    foreach (ManagementObject mo in processes)
                    {
                        DataRow row = result.NewRow();
                        if (mo["Name"] != null)
                            row["Name"] = mo["Name"].ToString();
                        row["ProcessId"] = Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessId"]);
                        if (mo["Caption"] != null)
                            row["Caption"] = mo["Caption"].ToString();
                        result.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
const string queryString = "SELECT Name, ProcessID, Caption FROM Win32_Process";

var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\root\cimv2");
var query = new ObjectQuery(queryString);
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
var objectCollection = searcher.Get();

foreach (var o in objectCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", o["Name"], o["ProcessID"], o["Caption"]);
}
```

...works fine for me. Exactly how is your code not working?

(You don't appear to be doing anything with `options`, by the way).

**Update:**

It's actually complaining because you've not set up the columns in your `DataTable`. I think that you've cut down your example too much. Your `DataTable` is called "Win32_Process", yes? If I call mine "Albert":

```
var table = new DataTable("Albert");
```

I get `Column 'Name' does not belong to table Albert.`

You need to do something like the following:

```
var table = new DataTable("Albert");
table.Columns.Add("Name");
table.Columns.Add("ProcessID", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Caption");
```

Comment: Hi, I change my code, now I don't stock in a Datarow and it works.
I think I have problem when i try row["Name"] = mo["Name"].ToString(); do you know why ?

Comment: See my update; you've not added any columns to your `DataTable`.